# How to import and use csvkit in a Python script

Tags: python, csv, python-import

I feel like this is a silly question. I've found a python library I need to use. Specifically [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/) . I need to use this in an existing application I've created. However, all of the example usage I've been able to see is from the command line where arguments are passed like this:

```
in2csv ne_1033_data.xlsx > data.csv
```

Would I be able to import this and use it within my application? Something along the lines of:

```
from csvkit import in2csv
in2csv(ne_1033_data.xlsx, data.csv)
```

Thanks for helping me out. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: Have you tried reading [relevant the csvkit manual](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lib.html)? And [some examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [csvkit manual](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lib.html):

```
import csvkit
```

Is what you are looking for.

After importing, I'm assuming that the command syntax and data flow are similar to that of the [python `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-csv). Again this is based on the csvkit manual.

Comment: Aha! I missed the "Using as a Python library" section in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: @kevin.w.johnson there is no such section in the docs nowadays

Answer (score 5):

You should import convert and then use convert.xls2csv :

```
from csvkit import convert
inputfile = open(file.csv)
convert.xls2csv(inputfile)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `csvkit` like a python lib, just use `pip install csvkit` install it ,and import it in your script. you can look at the [document](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lib.html) to got APIs.

Answer (score -2):

This (I think) will do what you want:

```
import csvkit
import sys
inputName = sys.argv[1]
outputName = sys.argv[2]
input = open(inputName)
output = open(outputName)
in2csv(input, output)
```

From command line, you would call it like this:

```
nameOfPython.py inputFile.xlsx outputFile.csv
```

I'm not familiar with the csvkit module and am not in a position to download it, so I cannot test this for myself.

Comment: You cannot import in2csv